# If 0 is a point of Lebesgue density of $E\in\mathbb{R}$ and B a ball center in 0, why $B\bigcap E\bigcap -E$ has positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

From definition of Lebesgue density and invariance of measure, I can get $m(B\bigcap-E)=m(B\bigcap E)\geq(1-\epsilon)m(B)>0$, $\forall 0<\epsilon<1$, But I don't see how to conclude $m(B\bigcap E\bigcap-E)>0$. Isn't that possible to be the case that $E\bigcap-E=\emptyset$?

Comment: Can you give an example of such $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $E\cap -E = \emptyset$?

Comment: If I didn't get -E wrong, E=[1,2] and -E=[-2,-1] will be one?

Comment: But then $0$ would not be a point of Lebesgue density for $E$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Try to use

$$m(X\cap Y) = m(X) + m(Y) - m(X \cup Y)$$

Comment: then I will get $m(B\bigcap E\bigcap -E)\geq0$ which means there is E such that $m(B\bigcap E\bigcap -E)=0$, not strictly positive.

Comment: Here $X = B \cap E$, $Y = B \cap (-E)$, and $X \cup Y \subseteq B$.  What you get should be strictly positive if $\epsilon < 1/2$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I get little confused of the second part, why we can choose $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Unavailable: you said in the question you know you can pick such a $B$ for any $0<\epsilon<1$. So take $\epsilon=1/4$ for example.

Comment: @Dap Thx! I know where I got wrong just now. At first I wonder why I am able to ignore case like when $\epsilon=\frac{3}{4}$, but in fact when$\frac{1}{2}<\epsilon<1$, I will get measure great than a negative number which is trivial. Here is the new problem, what about the case for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$? the measure will be zero.